# How to prevent debug erorrs when using vector size as the criterion for a while loop?

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop

I created a program that turns a vector (numberset) of all integers from 2 to 100 into a list of just the prime numbers within that vector. It does so by removing numbers from the vector if they are divisible by a range of numbers other than themselves.

I had lots of trouble getting this code to run without a debug error, and ultimately determined that the problem was related to using the vector's size as part of the while loop condition. Because removing numbers from the vector would also reduce the vector's size, my loop variable (j) was probably 'jumping' over entries in the vector--possibly leading it to try to access non-existent vector sizes.

The solution I found was to decrement the loop variable by 1 whenever I also reduced the vector size. However, I was wondering whether there were other ways you might have solved this problem. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h" // available at http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h
#include <vector>

vector<int> numberset;
int j = 0;
int main()
{

    bool primetest = true;
    // Adding numbers to our list of potential primes (excluding the number 1)
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        numberset.push_back(i);
    }

    // j represents the current position within the vector numberset
    while (j <= numberset.size()-1)

        // We're going to look through all the numbers in the vector above, and then divide them by a set of divisors to verify that they're prime. Numbers in the above set that are divisible by a divisor will be removed, since they are not prime.
        {
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= 100; divisor++)
            // These are the numbers by which we will divide the vectors
        {
            //If a certain number within the vector (marked by position j) can be divided a different number >= 2 with a remainder of 0, we know it's not prime.
            //We will then set the 'primetest' bool to "false" (indicating that we know this is not a prime number)

            if (numberset[j] % divisor == 0 && numberset[j] != divisor)

            {
                primetest = false;
                if (primetest == false)
                {
                    //This line removes the non-prime number from our list of numbers.
                    numberset.erase(numberset.begin() + j);
                    //j-- is added in to prevent the code from 'skipping' over numbers in the numberset vector after a number within the vector is removed. 
                    //For example, let's say the third element in the vector (numberset[3]) is 6. If we remove 6 (since it's not prime), the third element then becomes 7, and the 4th element becomes 8. 
                    //However, the j++ below will cause us to next review (numberset[4]), which is 8 rather than 7. Thus the addition of j--, which cancels out the j++ and makes sure we're not skipping elements.
                    //j++ only runs if a number is erased from the vector, however.
                    j--;
                    }
            }
        }
        j++;


    }

    //This prints out the remaining prime numbers in the vector.
    for (int x : numberset)
    {
        cout << x << " ";

    }


}
```

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: `while (j <= numberset.size()-1)` should be `while (j < numberset.size())`, and `j` should be `vector<int>::size_type` instead of `int`. And you shouldn't be using `j--` inside the `for` loop at all. Maybe you meant to `break` the `for` loop? Then you can skip `j++` if `erase()` was called. But note that `primetest = false; if (primetest == false)` always evalulates as true so the `if` is useless

Comment: And after you switch it to a `size_type`, note that this is an unsigned number and will underflow if you try to subtract 1 from 0. Not sure how that changes your algorithm (I assume that's your problem right now), but you need to be aware.

Comment: I solve these kinds of problem by either not mutating the container I'm iterating over (instead using a separate result container, and possibly `std::swap` with the original container when finished), or by using the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point about not needing the if (primetest == false) condition; I removed that.

I found that changing numberset.size()-1 to numberset.size() resulted in a debug error. Without the -1, wouldn't the code try to access an element in the vector that was outside the vector's range?

Replacing j-- with break caused my code to produce 2 plus all odd numbers from 3 to 99.

Comment: In a single iteration of the outermost loop, how many times do you intend to execute the line `numberset.erase(numberset.begin() + j);`? Do some debugging to see what actually happens.